# How to put XML element's content into XUL template?

Tags: xml, templates, datasource, xul

I've gotten trouble with passing XML data into XUL template.

Look:

For example, we have the datasource XML with the next structure:

```
<people>
    <person name="Joe"/>
    <person name="Tom"/>
    <person name="Lisa"/>
    <person name="Bob"/>
</people>
```

In this case we may use the next template in XUL:

```
<template>
    <query expr="person"/>
    <action>
        <listitem uri="?" label="?name"/>
    </action>
</template>
```

The question is what should I put into the **listitem's label** attribute in case datasource XML has such structure:

```
<people>
    <person>Joe</person>
    <person>Tom</person>
    <person>Lisa</person>
    <person>Bob</person>
</people>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [using <assign>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL%3aTemplate_Guide%3aXML_Assignments):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window id="yourwindow" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

<people id="famouspeople" xmlns="">
  <person>Napoleon Bonaparte</person>
  <person>Cleopatra</person>
</people>

<listbox datasources="#famouspeople" ref="*" querytype="xml">
  <template>
    <query expr="person">
      <assign var="?name" expr="./text()"/>
    </query>

    <action>
      <listitem uri="?" label="?name"/>
    </action>
  </template>
</listbox>

</window>
```